# lsmeans and difflsmeans return no output for lmer object

Tags: r, lme4, confidence-interval, mixed-models

I'm trying to calculate the confidence intervals for fixed effects in an lmer mixed model, and difflsmeans and lsmeans simply return an empty table. I've tried lme() but am having trouble with model convergence (hence using lmer).

The data look like this (where bout is the dependent level 1 variable and TWaverage is the independent level 2 variable of interest and sex, location and RA are further nesting levels):

```
ID  bout TWaverage  sex location    RA
1   17  3.748333333 1   Big Society 1337
1   59  3.748333333 1   Big Society 1337
1   14  3.748333333 1   Big Society 1337
1   9   3.748333333 1   Big Society 1337
1   9   3.748333333 1   Big Society 1337
1   14  3.748333333 1   Big Society 1337
1   21  3.748333333 1   Big Society 1337
2   40  3.055833333 0   Big Society 1337
2   63  3.055833333 0   Big Society 1337
2   7   3.055833333 0   Big Society 1337
2   75  3.055833333 0   Big Society 1337
2   13  3.055833333 0   Big Society 1337
2   3   3.055833333 0   Big Society 1337
2   16  3.055833333 0   Big Society 1337
3   103 3.696666667 1   Big Society 1337
3   14  3.696666667 1   Big Society 1337
3   2   3.696666667 1   Big Society 1337
3   32  3.696666667 1   Big Society 1337
```

My model specification looks like this:

```
groupSizeRandom = lmer(bout ~ TWaverage + (TWaverage|ID), data, REML = F)
```

I'm calling the lsmeans like this (which I understand should give me the confidence intervals for all fixed effects in the model):

```
lsmeans(groupSizeRandom,test.effs = NULL)
```

However, it only returns an empty table (with no values):

```
Least Squares Means table:
     Estimate Standard Error DF t-value Lower CI Upper CI p-value
```

Anyone know why? Or how to calculate the CIs for the model I've specified above?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there are many bouts with the same `TWaverage` values. That is an obvious problem.

Comment: Well, you model has no predictors of class "factor", and I think it's looking for factors and not finding them.

Comment: It's not a problem. It's a level two predictor so you it doesn't have to have variance within the level two categories. rvl: what do you mean? TWaverage is a fixed factor in the model, in HML terms.

Comment: @ColeRobertson as yet, R does not incorporate a mind-reading algorithm so it doesn't know sex is a factor unless you tell it so. That's why the wording about class "factor".

Comment: @rvl I appreciate that R needs to know what the factors are. But sex isn't a factor in this model, and the coefficients tell me that R is in fact treating groupID as a factor not a continuous variable. Specifying it as a factor in any case does not cause the lsmeans table to populate, so I think the problem lies elsewhere, but thanks.

Comment: Where? Your lmer call has TWaverage as the ONLY fixed effect. Typically, lsmeans are only computed at levels of fixed effects.

Comment: BTW, there are two R packages that have an lsmeans function. You seem to be using lmerTest package. But I think if you use the lsmeans package, you'll get ONE lsmean -- the prediction at the average value of TWaverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

- If you just want the confidence intervals of the fixed-effect parameters, you can get likelihood profile CIs via `confint(groupSizeRandom)` or Wald CIs via `confint(groupSizeRandom,method="Wald")` (see `?confint.merMod`).
- as pointed out in the comments, there are two `lsmeans` functions

  - `lmerTest::lsmeans` will only report lsmeans for `factor` variables. As also pointed out in the comments, "factor" has a specific meaning in R - it means a **categorical** predictor (independent) variable. `TWaverage` is a continuous predictor, so in R terms it's not a "factor".
  - `lsmeans::lsmeans` will give you what you ask for if you use `lsmeans(groupSizeRandom,spec="TWaverage")` ...